# How to use password/login in TortoiseHg with Two-factor enabled?

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg, kiln

I used TortoiseHg version control software with Kiln repositories.
I always used password and login to pull or push, etc.
After I enabled two-factor authenticatation, I started to get "Authorization failed, code 255" error. I know for sure, that the password is correct.

The question is: how to use HTTPS repos with two-factor authentication enabled?
I can't use SSH for some other reasons.